# Dynamic Time Series Function R

Tags: r, function, time-series

I currently have a time series of football data for weekly stats for variables such as shots and goals.  I want to create a "form" function with input for number of games (specify date) and the variable of choice (shots, goals, etc) so that I can check the form of players for certain stats over the last 4 games, 6 games or whatever period I specify. The data frame is of the form:

```
week = as.vector(c(rep(25, 5), rep(26, 5), rep(27, 5)))
date = as.vector(c(rep("2019-08-09 15:00:00", 5), rep("2019-08-16 15:00:00", 5), rep("2019-08-23 15:00:00", 5)))
players = c("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", "Player 5")
name = as.vector(c(rep(players, 3)))
goals = as.vector(sample(c(0:2), 15, replace = T))
shots = as.vector(sample(c(0:8), 15, replace = T))

data = data.frame(week, date, name, goals, shots)
```

Would it make sense to create a function using dplyr and input variables for time period and variable type?  Or is there some package that will do this for me?

Comment: The question is not clear. 1) you want code to parse that file format? (Your example is not a data frame, it's not in tabular form). 2) each week is followed by many players' data? 3) what marks the beginning of a new table row, a field `"week"`?

Comment: I have edited the post to include a snapshot of how the data is formatted.  I want to be able to extract data sets based on certain conditions.  There are multiple weeks (and years) and I want to be able to search for the last 18 months or perhaps last 5 games to compare statistics.

Comment: I have edited my answer to address what you have specified in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer could give you some idea how to filter the data frame for date or games played as specified in the comments:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data = tibble(
  week = rep(31:40, each = 2),
  date = seq.Date(ymd("2019-01-01"), length.out = 20, by = "months"),
  name = paste0("player", rep(1:4, each = 5)),
  goals = sample(c(0:2), 20, replace = T),
  shots = sample(c(0:8), 20, replace = T)
)


# last 3 months or after
data %>%
  filter(date > (today() %m-% months(3) ))

# last 5 games
data %>%
  filter(week > (max(week) - 4) )
```